# Download file in Zend 1 (PHP): File name is japanese

Tags: zend-framework, filenames

I using `Zend FW 1` to download file.

File need download have file name japanese : `るファイルを選択.pdf`

`$this->path:` is file path  . Ex : `D:\るファイルを選択.pdf`

This is my code in PHP

```
public function send() {
    if($this->checkPath()) {
        // fileinfo extention enable
        $type = mime_content_type($this->path);

        if ($this->getRequest()->isSecure()) { // HTTPS sites - watch out for IE! KB812935 and KB316431.
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=10');
            header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', 0) .' GMT');
            header('Pragma: ');
        } else { //normal http - prevent caching at all cost
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
            header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', 0) .' GMT');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
        }

        if ($this->isIE()) {
            $name = rawurlencode($this->name);
        } else {
            $name = $this->s($this->name);
        }

        $name =  urlencode($name);
        $Disposition = "attachment;filename*=UTF-8''$name";
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', $type . ";charset=utf-8")
                            ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', $Disposition, true)
                            ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true)
                            ->setHeader('X-Sendfile', readfile($this->path), true)
                            ->sendResponse();

        unlink($this->path);
    }
}
```

But `mime_content_type($this->path)` retun :

> mime_content_type(D:\るファイルを選択.pdf): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in ...

I had set `UTF-8` in `getResponse`

Comment: It's work fine `mime_content_type()` for  japanese file name. Maybe your path is wrong or file does not  exists.

Comment: I checked file then see file path correct and file exists

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `finfo`

```
$result = new finfo();
echo $result->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
```